# How to keep track of free nodes in a linked list implemented using an array of nodes without traversal?

Tags: c, linked-list

I have implemented a linked list similar to as described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Linked_lists_using_arrays_of_nodes

My question is as stated in the title. After I free a linked list from the array of nodes I need to know which nodes are free for use without traversal (Design constraint).

I have been keeping track of free nodes using a counter that just states the number of nodes used. But after freeing a list, The counter would not be useful or accurate anymore.

Comment: By making another linked list of free nodes. If a node is needed take one from that linked list (if any) else take the next unused array element (if any) else reallocate a bigger array. If the linking is done by array index (instead of by pointer) nothing breaks by reallocating the array.

Comment: Or if the order is not important, once could place all the free nodes in the beginning/end of the list (maintaining a pointer to the first free/non-free node). Each time a node is freed, it needs to be removed and re-added in the free nodes cluster